# how to execute python script on remote machine using psexec?

Tags: python, windows, psexec

I am trying to execute a python script on remote machine using psexec. The python script is already on the remote machine i only want to execute it there. I am using the following command:

```
psexec -i -s -d \\123 -u xyz -p xyz C:/sample.py
```

But i get error as :

```
PsExec could not start C:\sample.py on 123:
The system cannot find the file  specified
```

I tried placing the python exe path also in the psexec comand as:

```
psexec -i -s -d \\123 -u xyz -p xyz C:\programs\python.exe C:/sample.py
```

then it opens the python.exe but does not execute the sample.py. The paths are all correct. But i am not getting why the psexec command is not able to find the script. Please suggest how shall i execute the script on the remote machine using psexec.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-d` option from the command and provide the path in quotes and use backslash in path

Answer (score 0):

try adding " " around the exe filename

```
psexec -i -s -d \\123 -u xyz -p xyz "C:\programs\python.exe" C:/sample.py
```

if it doesn't work, try adding " " also around the parameters

```
psexec -i -s -d \\123 -u xyz -p xyz "C:\programs\python.exe" "C:/sample.py"
```